# Exposing a server-side Blazor GUI on only one specific AspNetCore endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

My understanding is that a typical Blazor setup looks roughly as follows:

```
class Startup
{
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
      services.AddRazorPages();
      services.AddServerSideBlazor();
  }


  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger, IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime)
  {
      app.UseStaticFiles();
      app.UseRouting();
    
      app.UseEndpoints(x =>
      {
          x.MapBlazorHub();
          x.MapFallbackToPage("/", "/_Host");
      });
  }
}
```

The middleware added in Configure() then seems to apply to all of the host's endpoints.

Is there any way to configure AspNetCore so that all middleware required by Blazor is only added to/invoked on one particular endpoint, whereas any other endpoints remain untouched?

For context, I'm writing a library that should allow users to add a blazor-based GUI to their existing AspNetCore apps.
The setup of this GUI should interfere as little as possible with the original host config. For example, the original host might itself host some web front end whose request paths might clash with the GUI the library is trying to add.

To avoid that, my idea so far was for the library-provided GUI to be hosted on a separate endpoint/port. However, that doesn't add much benefit unless I can actually configure this endpoint separately from others - meaning, things like .UseRouting(), .UseEndpoints() etc should only apply to the specific library endpoint.

Is there any way to do so? If not, are there any other ways to have this type of separation?

The only other way I could think of would be for the library to create its own WebHost altogether, and add some form of HostedService to the original host which starts/stops the child-host. That feels awfully hacky and inefficient though - surely, there must be a nicer way.

Comment: It seems [UseWhen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.usewhenextensions.usewhen?view=aspnetcore-7.0) fit your requirement, It can  creates a branch in the request pipeline according to your request url, then rejoined to the main pipeline